# Spring MVC Static Resource Mapping

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I have the following servlet mapping present -

```
  <!--  Mapping Static Resources -->
     <mvc:resources mapping="/css/**" location="/resources/css/" />
     <mvc:resources mapping="/js/**" location="/resources/js/" />
     <mvc:resources mapping="/images/**" location="/resources/images/" />
```

My image link in the html is "/images/folder/imageName.jpg" - These images get me a 404 whereas if the change the link to  "/images/imageName.jpg" and move the image to directly under the images folder it gets me the image.

Do I need to modify my servlet mapping in any way to take into account the hierarchical structure?

Comment: This looks correct... have you checked in Firebug for the URLs the browser is using to fetch the images?  There may be a relative path issue.

Comment: Could you give us the actual folder structure.From the mapping i understand /images is mapped to '/resources/images/' assuming the images are directly under /resources/images/ directory.   So why would you access it "/images/folder/imageName.jpg"  unless the image directory is '/resources/images/folder/'

Answer (score 3):

You need to modify links to the images. When you write

```
<mvc:resources mapping="/images/**" location="/resources/images/" />
```

Then your HTTP requests to `/resources/images` are translated to `webapp/images` folder on the server. So in the html you should have something like this:

```
<img src="<spring:url value='/resources/images/logo.png'/>"
```