# How to map css/image/js folder in spring mvc

Tags: spring-mvc

Will the code below is correct to map the contents of css/images/js folders in spring mvc properly. I moved around my folders but couldnt find proper places for it.

web.xml

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>default</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.css</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

I want my folders locate under WEB-INF so my 
spring-servlet.xml:

```
<mvc:resources location="/WEB-INF/" mapping="**"/>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Spring MVC Static Resource Mapping](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14544854/spring-mvc-static-resource-mapping)

Comment: Thank, I couldnt search for that post. So do I need to configure in web.xml?

Comment: No in your `dispatcher-servlet.xml`

Answer (score 0):

Add  this code in servlet-context.xml

```
 <resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" cache-period="31556926"/>
```